# Insert date field into MS Access table fires run-time error 3075

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I would like to insert some data into a table in Microsoft Access but I always get the error:

```
Run-time error '3075':
Syntax error in date in query expression '#10.10.2016'.
```

This is my SQL query that is sent to the database:

```
INSERT INTO USECASE_STATUS (usecase_id, usecase_status_txt_id, version, planned_delivery, last_delivery, comment) 
VALUES ( 37, 1, Null, #01.01.2015#, Null, Null)
```

What is wrong with this statement? The database column `planned_delivery` and `last_delivery` are both defined as "`Date/Time`" - "`Short Date`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that error is that you have used dots to separate date part from each other. The only date separators accepted in Access query are dash (-) and slash (/).

You need to change your query like that:

```
INSERT INTO USECASE_STATUS (usecase_id, usecase_status_txt_id, version, planned_delivery, last_delivery, comment) 
VALUES ( 37, 1, Null, #01-01-2015#, Null, Null)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO USECASE_STATUS (usecase_id, usecase_status_txt_id, version, planned_delivery, last_delivery, comment) 
VALUES ( 37, 1, Null, #01/01/2015#, Null, Null)
```

Comment: Also, don't forget that the format of the string expression for your date must be `#yyyy/mm/dd#` or `#mm/dd/yyyy#`.